# remove seconds when displaying a datetime database value

Tags: php, sql, datetime, datepicker

I have an html form that uses jQuery datetimepicker to send a value to a database but with out seconds so the value created in the database 'datetime column always has '00' for the seconds.
I want to remove the seconds when I display the value on a webpage.
I currently have:

```
<?php echo $row_rsEnquiriesList['contact_date_e']; ?>
```

which displays something like this - 26-12-08 12:40:00.

I would like it to display this - 26-12-08 12:40

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it as follow

```
<?php 

echo date('d-m-y H:i',strtotime($row_rsEnquiriesList['contact_date_e']));

?>
```

It will remove seconds. and you can remove anything you need.

Comment: Thats it.. Thanks Gowtham!

Comment: Nice solution, but the output is different. It seems strtotime change "something"... your code shows: `08-12-26 12:40` and he wants `26-12-08 12:40`

Comment: in date function change 'd', m or y according to your need. Here is the reference http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<?php echo substr($row_rsEnquiriesList['contact_date_e'],0, 14); ?>` but is much better to format it on the sql. In this way the date stays as string.